# Procura Duplicidade na tabela

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela com 3 milhões de telefones, e tenho o código de cada cliente. 
Meu objetivo é encontrar qual telefone repete em diferentes clientes.

Para isso, eu consigo fazer a contagem de quantas vezes ele repete, porém não consigo saber para quem ele repete.

Segue um exemplo do código.

```
SELECT      PARCEIRO
        ,   TELEFONE
        ,   COUNT(TELEFONE) AS QTD
FROM        tabela
GROUP BY    TELEFONE
        ,   PARCEIRO
HAVING      COUNT(*)>1
ORDER BY    COUNT(PARCEIRO)
```

Comment: `FROM tabela;` esse _`;`_ encerra antes do agrupamento.. não é esse o problema?

Comment: Ah desconsiderar a ;, erro de digitação hehe.

Comment: Porem se eu rodo o codigo, ele me tras a quantidade certinha , porem legal tenho a quantidade de repetiçoes mas o que eu quero e saber para quem ele repete.

Comment: Corrigi acentuação, e retirei todas as tags. Caso não for MySQL, coloque SOMENTE a tag do seu banco de dados, pois trata-se de um caso específico, e não geral.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer join usando a mesma tabela com aliases diferentes, segue o exemplo:

```
SELECT t1.PARCEIRO, t1.TELEFONE FROM tabela as t1
JOIN tabela as t2
    /* mesmo telefone */
    ON t1.TELEFONE = T2.TELEFONE 
    /* parceiro diferente */
    and t1.PARCEIRO <> t2.PARCEIRO /* and t1.PARCEIRO != t2.PARCEIRO */
ORDER BY t1.PARCEIRO, t1.TELEFONE
```

Comment: Voce e o cara <3

Answer (score 3):

Olha, não precisa aplicar nenhum tipo de join. Esse daqui é mais simples e ate acho mais performante ainda. E eu acho que assim mesmo funcionaria:

```
SELECT      COUNT(*) AS QTD,PARCEIRO,TELEFONE FROM tabela
GROUP BY    PARCEIRO, TELEFONE
HAVING      COUNT(*)>1
ORDER BY    QTD
```