# Consultar funcionarios com nomes iguais e CPF diferentes

Tags: sql-server

Problema:
Preciso consultar funcionários que possuem nomes iguais porém com CPF diferentes.

Segue exemplo da estrutura da tabela

```
create table #tmp (nome varchar(255), cpf varchar(255))

insert into #tmp values ('lucas tiago', '35859764847')
insert into #tmp values ('lucas tiago', '12345678980')
insert into #tmp values ('joao da silva', '35859764847')
insert into #tmp values ('joao santos', '12345678981')
```

---

```
nome             cpf
lucas tiago      35859764847
lucas tiago      12345678980
joao da silva    35859764847
joao santos      12345678981
```

No exemplo acima, o funcionario lucas tiago tem 2 cadastros, porem com cpf diferentes,
quero que traga apenas esses 2 registros.

Como fazer a consulta ?

Comment: Vê se te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/414077/procura-duplicidade-na-tabela/414082#414082

Comment: ué? Não seria só buscar pelo nome? Se nenhum CPF se repete, só haverá um "Fulano Silva" com CPF 123, mas se existe outro "Fulano Silva" com CPF 456, e vc realizar a busca pelo nome "Fulano Silva", vai retornar todos os: Fulano Silva. Não é isso ou há outra questão fora esse SELECT .. `nome LIKE '%Fulano Silva%'`. Fiquei curioso e seria interessante vc colocar no corpo da questão a instrução SQL que vc montou, como está o seu SELECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso, teria que fazer um join com a mesma tabela linkando o nome e utilizando having count:

````
SELECT 
    
    #TMP.NOME
    ,#TMP2.CPF
    
FROM 
    #TMP
JOIN
    #TMP AS #TMP2
ON #TMP2.NOME = #TMP.nome

GROUP BY
    #TMP.NOME,
    #TMP2.CPF

HAVING COUNT(#TMP.NOME) > 1```
````

Comment: Ótimo, resolveu meu Problema. Muito Obrigado!